# TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE and process threads in linux kernel development using C

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I have a running process which has created multiple user mode threads. If the kernel changes the state of the process to `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` (or `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`) do the threads created by the process automatically get suspended?

This is not a homework question. I'm reading an operating systems book which describes how a semaphore is implemented. In their implementation the semaphore struct maintains a linked list of processes currently waiting for the semaphore. From what I've learned so far, such a semaphore could only be used to synchronize processes, not threads. Correct? The threads in the linked list are put into a `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` state until the semaphore is available, at which point one process is woken up by setting its state to `TASK_RUNNING`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Linux each thread is a separate `task` running within a process scope. See `/proc/self/task/`. They are even created with the same kernel function as a new process. Threads in Linux originated as "lightweight processes".
Each task has a unique task id (`tid`), similar to the process id (`pid`) and indeed the master thread (the one executing main()) has the same `tid` as the process `pid`.

The only functional difference in Linux between threads and processes is that all threads (tasks) share all process resources apart from

- scheduling parameters (includes `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE`, `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`)
- stack
- task id
- the `main()` thread identifies the process

So `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` can be applied to each thread individually.

As such semaphores are perfectly valid to use for synchronising threads. In this case if one thread blocks on a semaphore, it's jus that one thread.

Comment: Now it makes sense. I guess in the book's implementation their linked list of processes is probably a linked list of task_struct, which would account for processes and threads. I wish they would have made that clearer. Thanks.